# iPhone: Use a view as a transparent overlay with closing button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've got a map with three bar buttons for different markers to show up in the map. If I click on a bar button, the specific markers are shown in the map, which already works great.

Now I would like to show a transparent overlay (popup window) with the description of the markers after I clicked on a bar button with a button to close the overlay again and show the markers (which are set in the background).

The function of the bar button:

```
- (IBAction)routeTwo:(id)sender
{
    // The code for the overlay
    // ...

    // remove any annotations that exist
    [map removeAnnotations:map.annotations];  

    // Add any annotations which belongs to route 2
    [map addAnnotation:[self.mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:2]];
    [map addAnnotation:[self.mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:3]];
    [map addAnnotation:[self.mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:4]];
    [map addAnnotation:[self.mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:5]];
}
```

I tried the following possibilities:

**1. Using a modal view controller**

```
RouteDescriptionViewController *routeDescriptionView = [[RouteDescriptionViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:routeDescriptionView animated:YES];
    [routeDescriptionView release];
```

Works great, but the problem is: The map view in the background is not visible anymore (configuring alpha values of the modal view doesn't change anything).

**2. Add RouteDescriptionView as a subview**

```
RouteDescriptionViewController *routeDescriptionView = [[RouteDescriptionViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:routeDescriptionView.view];
    [routeDescriptionView release];
```

Works great as well, but the problem here is: I can't configure a close button on the subview to close/remove the subview (RouteDescriptionView).

**3. Using UIAlertView**

Would work as expected, but the UIAlert is not really customizable and therefore not suitable  for my needs.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: I think option 2 is your best choice.  Why can't you put a button on the subview?  That should not be a problem.

Comment: I didn't think about adding a button on the subview. As you can see below, it worked! Thank you as well for pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go with option 2, you can add an instance of UIButton as a subview of routeDescriptionView, and connect that button to routeDescriptionView's removeFromSuperview method.

For example, in your RouteDescriptionViewController's loadView or viewDidLoad method:

```
UIButton *closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[closeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[closeButton addTarget:[self view] action:@selector(removeFromSuperview) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[[self view] addSubview:closeButton];
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you! I just didn't think about adding a UIButton as a subview to the subview.

The only thing I had to add was the user interaction, because it didn't do anything clicking on the close button:

closeButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;